# slow loop when automating Excel

Tags: vbscript

I need to create an excel sheet which contains a visual representation of a bit array. Presently I test the bit value and update the cell contents

```
For h = 1 To 128
    value = Mid(array, h,1)
    If value = "1" Then
        xl.Application.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(129 - h,5).value = "X"
    Else
        xl.Application.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(129 - h,5).value = ""
    End If
Next
```

If I add a `WScript.Sleep 100` before Next then the output result in the excel sheet is correct.

If not, then the X's are in the wrong places.

Initially I thought that it was Excel that was slow, so I tried making a CSV file that I could simply import later, but with the same results: too fast and the X's are in the wrong positions, slow it down and they are correct.

There are around 128 of these 128bit arrays, and if each takes 3 ~ 5 seconds then making this sheet will take forever.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this quickly? I am open to other ideas/solutions (with VBS) outputting the excel file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the array into the range in one go, like this

```
    ReDim dat(1 To 128, 1 To 1)
    For h = 1 To 128
        v = Mid$(arr, h, 1)
        dat(129 - h, 1) = IIf(v = "1", "X", "")
    Next
    xl.Application.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 5).Resize(128, 1).Value = dat
```

Comment: Thanks for that reply, @chris neilsen. I used the standard "IF Then Else EndIF" since VBS does not support the Iif statement. The problem occurs when **creating** the array, not the transposing it. I proved this to myself by making a CSV file, the results are _incorrect_ when running _full speed_ but correct when a WScript.Sleep 100 is added between "For.... Next" looping. This correct array can then be transposed to the Excel sheet.

Comment: The bit array **representation** is incorrect when created at full speed. The reduced speed is _not_ because it is written to the excel sheet one at a time but rather _because slowing down the "For......Next" loop gives a correct bit array representation_.

Comment: I suggest you post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so others can test for themslves.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (tested in [vbscript](/questions/tagged/vbscript) rather than [vba](/questions/tagged/vba)).

As it uses an array, the `""` output as part of an `IF` is redundant as the array is blank, so it is only necessary to write the *X* when the bit is 1.

```
Dim StrArr
Dim xl

Set xl = CreateObject("excel.application")
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Add

'sample array
StrArr = "1100111011001110110011101100111011001110110011101100111011001110110011101100111011001110110011101100111011001110110011101100111"
Dim X(128, 1 )

For lngrow = 1 To UBound(X)
    If Mid(StrArr, lngrow, 1) = "1" Then X(lngrow, 0) = 1
Next

wb.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 5).Resize(UBound(X), 1).Value = X
xl.Visible = True
```